# Can the raycast node be used with some kind of smooth falloff?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it possible to use the raycast node to make a shrinkwrap where we have a smooth falloff and not a hard transition like I show in the picture? I know I can solve this with a *Shrinkwrap* modifier and weight painting, but I am interested in doing it with *Geometry Nodes*.

[image]

Comment: Doing the falloff is easy, just calculate the distance to the edge and pass it to a float curve, where you control the shape of the falloff. The actual problem is how to find the distance to the edge.

Comment: A little bit under-specified, IMO.. are you looking for a smooth fall-off between 'hit' and 'miss' ? Or are you looking to simulate _Shrinkwrap_ 's response to vertex-weights more generally? How do you want the weights to be determined?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be easier to detect the falloff inside the road instead. It will need a larger "bed" for it to work and be able to put the final road inside of it. Still thinking about it, though as there are not several solutions that came to my mind at this moment.
[image]